# How to retrieve environment variables defined on an AWS Lambda function

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, boto3

I have a function where I want to list lambda environment variables but I cannot get the values just the names:

```
import boto3

l_client = boto3.client('lambda')
func_resp = l_client.get_function(FunctionName='arn:aws:lambda:us-west-1:111111111111:function:RedshiftPut')
env_vars = func_resp['Configuration']['Environment']['Variables']
for env_var in env_vars:
    print(env_var)
```

This gives me the environment name but not the value.

I can get the values using a name from the list:

```
print(env_vars['FILE_NAME']) #from the list I got from print(env_var)
```

How do I get the values?

Answer (score 2):

Your `env_vars` is a Python **dictionary** in the format of:

```
{'Key11': 'Value1', 'Key2': 'Value2'}
```

You could show the values like this:

```
for key in env_vars:
    print(key, env_vars[key])
```

Basically, the `for` loop returns provides the `key`. You can then use the key with the dictionary to return the value: `env_vars[key]`

You can also access them together like this:

```
for key, value in env_vars:
    print(key, value)
```